# How to insert a serialized json string into another json object /nested?

Tags: java, json, arraylist, flexjson

I have json serialized arraylist in java which i want to insert into another json object, how can i do this without having double quotes on my json string?

```
JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
String serializedList = serializer.serialize(myArrayList);
```

I want serializedList nested into my json object:

```
myJsonOutput = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                            .add("key1", "val1")
                                .add("key2", "val2")
                                .add("myArray", serializedList)
                            .build();
```

If i do it like this my serializedList will be inserted as a whole string?

Comment: Why don't you want double quotes?  The serializer will insert escapes appropriately.

Comment: (If you want it inserted as normal JSON, you need to deserialize it and insert that, not the serialized string.)

Comment: @HotLicks well my question is then: How do i insert my java ArrayList in my json object? Do i have to serialize it (with flexjson or gson) and then deserialize it into an object again?

Comment: You insert it like you'd insert anything else.  An ArrayList maps directly to a JSON "array".